# How to reopen a background application?

Tags: screenshot, onkeypress, background-foreground

I wanto to take a screenshot of the actual screen.
If i press a button, I set the following code to be executed:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

In this way I have the homescreen,but if I try to take screenshot, I take always mine application screen,before the new (Home).
I've used a Thread.sleep to wait for the new screen (Home),and than I take the screenshot, but alway I take mine last application string.
Why?
I think can be used a KeyPressed event to launch the tackeScreenshot(), and than come back to the application home screen.
Can be a good solution? If yes, how I can come back to mine application wich is running in background?
Cheeres =)

Answer (score 0):

You can't force your application to come back to the foreground. That would be an exploit leading to some extremely annoying applications. You'll have to find another way to take the screenshot of your home screen. I can't think of a way to do it though. It seems other people who are trying to do the same thing as you aren't having much success either:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374058/taking-homescreen-screenshot-on-android

Comment: Uhm....damn.Why if i try to take screenshot,i always take the last screen of mine application an not the "actually visualized" screen? oO'

Comment: I would guess because your screenshot command is coming from within your application, so the Context is within your application.

Comment: Any suggestion?Can be changed the Context? =)

Comment: You can try using the ActivityManager or WindowManager, but I don't have any experience with those system services, sorry. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: im tryng to use a service instead of an activity.
But in the service i cant call some methods becouse of findViewById.
How i can solve?Can i use the takeScreenShot() method in the activity and than call it in the service?If yes,how?
I also tryng to catch some event,always in the service,like keyPressed for the volume button,but is impossible...it works only in the activity...HELP! =(